# Camera Events Dronekit

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit, 3dr

Is it possible to take an image or video using dronekit for 3DR solo?

Is there an event to listen to when a pilot takes a snapshot or video from ground control station?

Answer (score 0):

https://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/idiot-s-guide-to-dronekit-python-a-journey-to-whoz-chillin

use listener on GOPRO_SET_RESPONSE